# bundle product with configuration options magento

Tags: magento, configurable

I want to create bundle product with configurable options in Magento. I can only add simple products in bundle of product.
Is there anyway to do so using extension or using Magento. I have searched but din't find any proper solution plz help.
I want something like this:

- configurable - dress size, dress pattern bundle of above dress +
  accessories + box (for inventory)
- only 2 dress packages shown as bundles products as above each with 5 inventory trackable items

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I found following page, but unfortunately I didn't manage to get the code working:
http://www.brimllc.com/2010/12/magento-grouped-products-containing-associated-configurable-products/

changing

```
<allowed_selection_types>
  <simple/>
  <virtual/>
</allowed_selection_types>
```

to

```
<allowed_selection_types>
  <simple/>
  <virtual/>
  <configurable/>
</allowed_selection_types>
```

in the file "/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml" may be a first step???

Comment: Thanks for ans.i think its for grouped product in my case it should be bundled product.